# Wordpress template based off starkers adds white space to admin-ajax.php ajax calls?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

When attempting to validate Stripe while using Gravity Forms and their new Stripe plugin both of my Secret keys fail to validate in the back end settings page. If I change to any of the "twenty" themes it works again.

While working with Gravity Forms support we've discovered that the ajax request is coming back valid however it is being padded with white space (Example from my theme: http://grab.by/y2SE).

Where should I begin troubleshooting? What part of a template would add white space to all /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php calls?

Comment: That looks like the dreaded `0` ajax response that WordPress gives if the ajax call isn't valid.  But, to answer your question - you should be checking for any hooks (actions / filters) in the theme that my be trying to access / alter the ajax functionality.

Comment: I get the "0" by navigating to /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. I get a valid response from the plugin. Ill Start looking into the actions/filters!

Comment: After a bit of research, it would seem that the most likely candidate could / would be `admin_init`, which is actually called / triggered during an ajax request.  If there was an `admin_init` action being called that was outputting a few characters, that would cause this problem...

Comment: A search has revealed that admin_init isn't mentioned once in the theme causing the conflict.